# Slider UI: Start at 20:00 end at 07:00?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to select venue closing time using a Slider. From tutorials, I've been able to put [together a simple slider](http://jsfiddle.net/TRABs/2/), however what I want to do is create a range from 20:00 to 07:00, meaning that once it passes the 23:59 mark it goes back to 00:00.

This is what I have so far.

```
$( "#open-till" ).slider({
range: "min",
value: 1230,
min: 0,
max: 1439,
step: 30,
slide: slideTime
});


function slideTime(event, ui){
    var val0 = $("#open-till").slider( "value" ),
        minutes0 = parseInt(val0 % 60, 10),
        hours0 = parseInt(val0 / 60 % 24, 10),
    startTime = getTime(hours0, minutes0);
    $("#time").text(startTime);
}
function getTime(hours, minutes) {
    minutes = minutes + "";
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
slideTime();
```

[See my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TRABs/2/)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display hours with modulo `%24`

Also change `min` and `max` values of the slider.
To get the actual time from the slider (if you want to send it to a server) it would be `value%1440` as I consider 7:00 to be `1890` in minutes (24 +7)

http://jsfiddle.net/TRABs/8/

Comment: There's a problem when switching from 20:30 to 20:00 and back to 20:30, for some reason the slider decrements `30` instead of adding `30` when going back from 20:00 to 20:30 so you get 19:30 instead, try to figure out why's that.

Comment: I just noticed something, however. When you slide the slider all the way to the beginning, and then one step further, it goes from 20:00 to 19:30. Why is that?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. It seems to be a bug with the slider itself as the value decrements instead of incrementing.

Comment: Updated. I now get the value of the slider using ui.value (not by selecting the slider). Other problem was that first time the ui was undefined so if it's undefined I set the slider to 20:30. Also changed so that instead of  `7:0` it outputs `7:00`